# making randomly positioned divs not overlap with each other and the sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a shop page where the different products are div elements whose positions are randomized upon the page loading with the following jQuery:

```
var docHeight = $(document).height(),
docWidth = $(document).width(),
$div = $('#div'),
divWidth = $div.width(),
divHeight = $div.height(),
heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

$div.css ({
    left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
    top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax )
});
```

---

I also have boostrap nav bars along the left side and bottom of the page, the divs "spawn" behind the fixed bottom bar and allow scrolling with no overlap so there is no problem there.

---

My two problems are:
**1)** The divs overlap and obstruct each other. I think the solution would be factoring the position and size of the previously spawned div into the spawning of the next but i dont know how i would put that into code.
[solved] **2)** the divs occasionally spawn on top of the nav bar on the left, overlapping it and obstructing the links. i think the solution would be to either specify a container for the divs to spawn in or exclude the width of the nav bar in the    **docWidth = $(document).width()** calculation but once again, i'm too unfamiliar with jQuery to solve this.
I made this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j1bpt34t/ repeatedly running the code demonstrates the problem. The nav bar shows up on top on the exmaple but on the site its fixed on  left.
Thank you for the help!

**Edit:** I solved problem two by calculating the width of the container with:

```
var $div = $('.navbar-fixed-left'),
navWidth = $div.width();
```

and subracting it from widthMax while adding it to the final left calulation like so:

```
widthMax = docWidth - divWidth - navWidth;
left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax + navWidth),
```

essentially shifing the spawn area over by the width of the navbar.

Comment: so, you want to position divs random on page not overlapping.. So you want metro style the div?

Comment: This is not what you're asking for, but please take a look at http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ and http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html if you haven't already :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wan't them to overlap you could get rid of the position absolute and add a float:left, in inherited position: static you won't get any overlap. Change the properties you are randomizing from top and left to margin-top and margin-left. You could also play with position: relative if you need a z-index but you could get some overlap there depending.

If you need the order random and/or you just don't want to take the time to make it look the way you want without position absolute; you could define all your variables at once and check them against eachother or better yet in a loop, and probably the variables in arrays. The checking would be something like the following:

```
var docHeight = $(document).height(),
  docWidth = $(document).width(),
  divWidth = $('#whiteTee').width(),
  divWidth2 = $('#blackTee').width(),
  divHeight = $('#whiteTee').height(),
  heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
  widthMax = docWidth - divWidth,
  widthMax2 = docWidth - divWidth2,
  randWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax),
  randWidth2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax2),
  checkFunction1;

checkFunction1 = function(randWidth, randWidth2){
    if(randWidth2 < randWidth){ /*THIS IS THE TRICKY PART, finding what in 
    your requirements for the if will be, you'll probably more likely need to 
    add your width in with the random number, and check that the second width 
    and second random number doesn't land it in the area of the other 
    container, going to get really tricky when you need to check all of them 
    against eachother. I mean you can keep copy pasting all your if 
    requirements, it will just be alot of things to check against.*/
       randWidth2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax2);
       return randWidth2;
    }
    else{
       randWidth2 = checkFunction1(randWidth, randWidth2);
       return randWidth2;
    }
}
randWidth2 = checkFunction1(randWidth, randWidth2);

$('#whiteTee').css({
  left: randWidth)
});

$('#blackTee').css({
  left: randWidth2),
});
```

Getting this exactly the way you want is probably going to be alot of work in javascript or alot of work in CSS, and it is usually a better idea to do all the heavy lifting you can in CSS.

Also try not for your own reading (or at least for those answering your stack overflows) to not use $ in your variables when using jquery.

Further, you keep redifining docHeight and docWidth, those look like they should really be defined once. And all of these var declarations are in the same scope level, so you only need the var in the first one, but what I was suggesting would mean declaring them and checking them all at once and then doing all the $(selector).css(css object assignment) stuff at the end, so it would get rid of that. But just for your future coding–sake, all those vars look unnecessary after that first one because they are all the same variable.

I didn't test this or actually do your problem for you, but hopefully this gives you an idea of the direction you need to take it.

Oh and to clarify, the if statement block as i have it is when it is in an area you want it, the else block would be when it is overlapping and needs to be reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

for problem nr. 2 :

you could use the a css style on your tee classes so that you have a top margin. No more overlapping the menu

```
margin-top: 50px;
```